# Regex to split on delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I have following string:

```
;Spe \,\:\; cial;;;
```

and I want to split it with semicolon as delimiter, however semicolon preceded by "\" should not be counted as delimiter. So I would like to get something like

```
["", "Spe \,\:\; cial", "", "", ""]
```

Update:

Java representation looks like:

```
String s = ";Spe \\,\\:\\; cial;;;";
```

Comment: Using backslash as an escape character, how do you want to handle "\\;"? (i.e. double-backslash semi-colon)

Comment: Yep sorry. \\; should be treated as separator - this is (escaped) backslash plus semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\\\\);
```

(Note that there's really only a single `\` in this expression -- ie, the expression should be `(?<!\);` -- but the backslash character has to be double-escaped: once for the benefit of the Java compiler, and again for the benefit of the regex engine.)

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong: Syntax error U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN near index 6 `(<!\);`

Comment: The code is:`String s = ";Spe \\,\\:\\; cial;;;";        
         String[] strs = s.split("(<!\\);", 5);`

Comment: Ah, ok, you might need `"(?<!\\\\);"` - escaping the \ once for the Java compiler's benefit, and escaping it again for the regex engine's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract the parts captured by the following regex : `;?([^;]*)\\\\?;`
So search this pattern in your string as long as a match is found :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";?([^;]*)\\\\?;");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while(matcher.find()){
   tokens.add(matcher.group(1));
}

String[] yourArray = tokens.toArray(new String[0]); // if you prefer an array 
                                                    // rather than a list
```

Comment: I got "U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET" on first line.

Comment: toArray always returns a `Object[]` use `toArray(new String(0))` to get a `String[]`

Comment: Yeah I should not have put the backslash in the first part, and I forgot to double escape the second one. Now it should be good.