# Splitting a line of a csv file into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, csv, vector, std

I have a function that will read a CSV file line by line. For each line, it will split the line into a vector. The code to do this is

```
    std::stringstream ss(sText);
    std::string item;

    while(std::getline(ss, item, ','))
    {
        m_vecFields.push_back(item);
    }
```

This works fine except for if it reads a line where the last value is blank. For example,

```
text1,tex2,
```

I would want this to return a vector of size 3 where the third value is just empty. However, instead it just returns a vector of size 2. How can I correct this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSV parser in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c)

Comment: no it's not. That code does exactly the same thing if the line ends with a comma

Comment: Isn't the problem the delimiter? `std::getline` extracts until the delimiter is found. But for the last item, there is no next delimiter `,` so nothing is extracted and thus the while loop ends.

Comment: @Jonnster: just because the currently accepted answer has flaws doesn't mean the other question doesn't address the same problem space adequately - there are other answers that should work and can be upvoted, and you can comment about problems with specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool addEmptyLine = sText.back() == ',';

/* your code here */

if (addEmptyLine) m_vecFields.push_back("");
```

or

```
sText += ',';     // text1, text2,,

/* your code */

assert(m_vecFields.size() == 3);
```

Comment: Yes I just added code like the first example and came back to find someone had suggested it. It's not the cleanest code but it'll do.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `boost::split` to do all this for you.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3207193

It has the behaviour that you require in one line.

### Example boost::split Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> strs;

    boost::split(strs, "please split,this,csv,,line,", boost::is_any_of(","));

    for ( vector<string>::iterator it = strs.begin(); it < strs.end(); it++ )
        cout << "\"" << *it << "\"" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Results

```
"please split"
"this"
"csv"
""
"line"
""
```

Comment: Why? `using namespace std` is a pretty normal thing to do, isn't it?
I don't think removing it would achieve anything @Seanny123, but feel free to do so in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function similar to this:

```
template <class InIt, class OutIt>
void Split(InIt begin, InIt end, OutIt splits)
{
    InIt current = begin;
    while (begin != end)
    {
        if (*begin == ',')
        {
            *splits++ = std::string(current,begin);
            current = ++begin;
        }
        else
            ++begin;
    }
    *splits++ = std::string(current,begin);
}
```

It will iterate through the string and whenever it encounters the delimiter, it will extract the string and store it in the splits iterator.
The interesting part is

- when current == begin it will insert an empty string (test case: "text1,,tex2")
- the last insertion guarantees there will always be the correct number of elements.
  If there is a trailing comma, it will trigger the previous bullet point and add an empty string, otherwise it will add the last element to the vector.

You can use it like this:

```
std::stringstream ss(sText);
std::string item;
std::vector<std::string> m_vecFields;
while(std::getline(ss, item))
{
    Split(item.begin(), item.end(), std::back_inserter(m_vecFields));
}

std::for_each(m_vecFields.begin(), m_vecFields.end(), [](std::string& value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

C++11 makes it exceedingly easy to handle even escaped commas using [regex_token_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_token_iterator/):

```
std::stringstream ss(sText);
std::string item;
const regex re{"((?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\.)*?)(?:,|$)"};

std::getline(ss, item)

m_vecFields.insert(m_vecFields.end(), sregex_token_iterator(item.begin(), item.end(), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator());
```

Incidentally if you simply wanted to construct a `vector<string>` from a CSV `string` such as `item` you could just do:

```
const regex re{"((?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\.)*?)(?:,|$)"};
vector<string> m_vecFields{sregex_token_iterator(item.begin(), item.end(), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator()};
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/cyVOkZ)]

Some quick explanation of the `regex` is probably in order. `(?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\.)` matches escaped characters or non-`','` characters. (See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902016/2642059) The `*?` means that it is not a greedy match, so it will stop at the *first* `','` reached. All that's nested in a capture, which is selected by the last parameter, the `1`, to `regex_token_iterator`. Finally, `(?:,|$)` will match either the `','`-delimiter or the end of the `string`.

## To make this standard CSV reader ignore empty elements, the regex can be altered to only match strings with more than one character.

```
const regex re{"((?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\.)+?)(?:,|$)"};
```

Notice the `'+'` has now replaced the `'*'` indicating 1 or more matching characters are required. This will prevent it from matching your `item` string that ends with a `','`. You can see an example of this here: http://ideone.com/W4n44W

Answer (score 2):

Flexible solution for parsing csv files:
where:

**source - content of CSV file**

**delimeter - CSV delimeter eg. ',' ';'**

```
std::vector<std::string> csv_split(std::string source, char delimeter) {
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::string word = "";
    int start = 0;

    bool inQuote = false;
    for(int i=0; i<source.size(); ++i){
        if(inQuote == false && source[i] == '"'){
            inQuote = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(inQuote == true && source[i] == '"'){
            if(source.size() > i && source[i+1] == '"'){
                ++i;
            } else {
                inQuote = false;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if(inQuote == false && source[i] == delimeter){
            ret.push_back(word);
            word = "";
        } else {
            word += source[i];
        }
    }
    ret.push_back(word);

    return ret;
}
```