# c++ reading csv file

Tags: c++, csv

I want to read csv file by using c++
so here is my code

```
 int main(){
 ifstream classFile("class.csv");
 vector<string> classData;

 while (getline(classFile, line,',')) // there is input overload classfile
        {
            classData.push_back(line);  

        }
}
```

here is my question : my problem is when it reads the last column of each row
(since it is not separated by comma) it reads last column data and first of next row data
for example if my data was like

className, classLocation, Professor
c++, Library, John

then it reads like className/ classLocation/ Professor c++/ Library / John

is there anyway that I can separate my last column from first of next row?
Thank you and sorry that it is confusing

Comment: CSV is supposed to have a end-of-line after each record. Does your csv has an end-of-line after each record? What you can do is first get the line and afterwards, divide using `,`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters-in-c  you are going to use 2 delimiter  `,` and `\n` in your case you are using only `,` so the `\n` becomes a part of the string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a line of a csv file into a std::vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310947/splitting-a-line-of-a-csv-file-into-a-stdvector)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Read the file line by line:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(stream, line)) ...
```

Pass each line to a istingstream and read the fields:

```
std::istringstream s(line);
std::string field;
while (getline(s, field,',')) ...
```

**Disclaimer**:
This is a simplified parsing of a csv-file.

Comment: Definitely in a loop of some kind. A while loop is a decent choice because you don't necessarily know how long the .csv file will be, and the terminating condition will just be running out of lines.

Comment: wow!! it works!! I have absolutely no idea how or why but it works!! XD thanks!!

Comment: and I guess it suppose to be istringstream s(line)? cuz istringstream(line) s does not work.. but thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, can I shove in some plain C into this thread?

Reading csv is pretty clear there:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  float f1, f2;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("file.csv", "r");

  while (fscanf(fp, "%g,%g\n", &f1, &f2) == 2)
    printf("%g\n", f1+f2);
}
```

And quite certainly it should work where C++ works.

There, in the `while`, we check how many objects fscanf has found: `fscanf(fp, "%g,%g\n", &f1, &f2) == 2` -- fscanf returns number of objects it finds.

I hope it might be of help to someone.

(And if anybody would like to see more info on `fscanf` and reading files -- leave some comments.)

Comment: Won't this break under the most trivial changes to the CSV format, for example having a space after the comma or a different (non-unix) line break?

Comment: yes, it most certainly will break.
And, adding to the problem of spaces in CSV file, the number of fields is fixed in the program, which is not the case with getline.
(Though, usually the number of fields is fixed in CSVs.)

Answer (score 2):

In case you are interested to have a `void` function to be called in your `main` section, please take a look at the following code:

```
void readCSV(const string &strPath2Dataset)
{   
    ifstream csvFile;
    string strPathCSVFile = strPath2Dataset + "/test.csv";
    csvFile.open(strPathCSVFile.c_str());

    if (!csvFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Path Wrong!!!!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    vector<long double> timeStampIMU;
    vector<long double> gyro_X;
    vector<long double> gyro_Y;
    vector<long double> gyro_Z;

    vector<long double> acc_X;
    vector<long double> acc_Y;
    vector<long double> acc_Z;

    string line;
    vector <string> vec;
    getline(csvFile, line); // skip the 1st line

    while (getline(csvFile,line))
    {
        if (line.empty()) // skip empty lines:
        {
            //cout << "empty line!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        istringstream iss(line);
        string lineStream;
        string::size_type sz;

        vector <long double> row;

        while (getline(iss, lineStream, ','))
        {  
            row.push_back(stold(lineStream,&sz)); // convert to double
        }

        timeStampIMU.push_back(row[0]);

        gyro_X.push_back(row[1]);
        gyro_Y.push_back(row[2]);
        gyro_Z.push_back(row[3]);

        acc_X.push_back(row[4]);
        acc_Y.push_back(row[5]);
        acc_Z.push_back(row[6]);
    }

    //cout << "size ts = " << timeStampIMU.size() << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < timeStampIMU.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "ts_imu = " << setprecision(12) << timeStampIMU[i] << endl;

        cout << "gx = " << setprecision(12) << gyro_X[i] << endl;
        cout << "gy = " << setprecision(12) << gyro_Y[i] << endl;
        cout << "gz = " << setprecision(12) << gyro_Z[i] << endl;

        cout << "ax = " << setprecision(12) << acc_X[i] << endl;
        cout << "ay = " << setprecision(12) << acc_Y[i] << endl;
        cout << "az = " << setprecision(12) << acc_Z[i] << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    }
}
```

My `.csv` file is dataset provided from IMU sensor, separated by comma:

```
TimeStamp, Gyro_X, Gyro_Y, Gyro_Z, Acc_X, Acc_Y, Acc_Z
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the functions I've found support escape character or consider anything other than `,` (like Unicode characters) as separators, even though the latter is often used in plain strings. So here's my version of DSV-reader, which supports escaping. It can escape separator, escape character and newline. You can convert types manually by checking the column index `i`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> DSVToArray(std::wstring text) {
    const wchar_t ch_sep = L'→';
    const wchar_t ch_esc = L'¶';
    const wchar_t ch_newline = L'\n';
    wchar_t pletter = L'\0';
    std::vector<std::wstring> columns = {L""};
    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> rows = {};
    int i = 0;
    int r = 0;
    bool unescaped = true;
    bool is_last = (0 >= text.size() - 1);
    for(std::string::size_type pos = 0; !is_last; ++pos) {
        wchar_t letter = text[pos];
        is_last = (pos >= text.size() - 1);
        if (ch_esc == letter) {
            if (!unescaped && pletter == ch_esc) {
                columns[i] += letter;
            }
            unescaped = !unescaped;
        }
        else if (ch_sep == letter && unescaped) {
            ++i;
            columns.push_back(L"");
            letter = L'\0';
        } else if (ch_newline == letter && unescaped || is_last) {
            if (L'\r' == pletter)
                columns[i] = columns[i].substr(0, columns[i].size() - 1);
            if (ch_newline != letter)
                columns[i] += letter;
            if (columns.size() == 1 && columns[0].size() == 0)
               break;
            rows.push_back({columns});
            columns = {L""};
            i = 0;
            letter = L'\0';
        }
        else {
            columns[i] += letter;
            if (!unescaped)
                unescaped = true;
        }
        pletter = letter;
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Example usage:

```cpp
std::wstring join(const std::wstring& sep, const std::vector<std::wstring>& values)
{
    std::wstringstream result;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++ )
        result << ( i ? sep : L"" ) << values[i];
    return result.str();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> result = DSVToArray(
        L"a¶→bc→ff¶¶ee\ncc→dd\nee→ff ff"
    );
    for (const auto& columns : result) {
        std::wcout << join(L" -> ", columns) << std::endl;
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Example's output:

```
a→bc -> ff¶ee
cc -> dd
ee -> ff ff
```