# How to add comma separated list of double values into a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, atof

I want to take the user's input which will be in this format-- (xx, xx, x) where the x is some arbitrary double value and there is always  a comma and whitespace after every value.

I've taken this input as a string value to parse it and check if the user didn't put anything funky. I'm having trouble turning the string into a double and then adding those values into a vector of double type. I tried using the atof function, but I am confused as to how i can add to the vector after the first element.

This is what I have so far in C++..

```
string vector1, vector2;

//asks for first vector

cout << "Enter first vector"<<endl;
getline(cin,vector1);

vector <double> Vector1;

//vector1 without the parantheses

vector1= vector1.substr(1,vector1.length()-2);
cout<< vector1<<endl;

Vector1.push_back(atof(vector1.c_str()));

cout<< Vector1[0];
```

Any ideas? I was thinking of making a loop but I don't how to tell the atof function to continue after the comma and whitespace.

Comment: You may want to use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse values from a line.

Comment: This should answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936483/c-reading-csv-file/19936571#19936571