# How can i pass comma separated values into a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

The text file provided has an undetermined number of lines, each line containing 3 doubles separated by commas. For example:

-0.30895,0.35076,-0.88403

-0.38774,0.36936,-0.84453

-0.44076,0.34096,-0.83035

...

I want to read this data from the file line by line and then split it on the comma(,) sign and save it in an N by 3 array, let's call it Vertices [N] [3], where N designates the undefined number of lines in the file.

My code so far:

```
void display() {
string line;
ifstream myfile ("File.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
    // I think the I should do 2 for loops here to fill the array as expected
    }
    myfile.close();

}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

}

**The Problem**: I managed to open the file and read line by line, but I have no idea how to pass the values into the requested array.
Thank you.

**EDIT**: 
I have tried modifying my code according to the suggestions i received to the following:

```
void display() {
string line;
ifstream classFile ("File.txt");
vector<string> classData;
if (classFile.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(classFile, line)) {
        std::istringstream s(line);
        std::string field;
        while (getline(s, field,',')) {
            classData.push_back(line);
        }
    }

    classFile.close();

}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

}

Is this the correct? and how can i access each field of the vector i created? (like in an array for example)?
I also noticed that these are of type string, how can i convert them to type float?
Thank you (:

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936483/c-reading-csv-file/19936571#19936571

Comment: If there are an undetermined number of lines, you should be using `std::vector`, not an ordinary 2d array, to store the data.

Comment: @DieterLücking I am fairly new to C++, in the answer you provided in the link, I should do 2 while loops? or did I misunderstand somewhere?

Comment: Yes/No - but if you have a fixed width of columns you can use a while/for (and ensure data consistency)

Comment: @DieterLücking I have edited my question above according to your suggestions, is this correct?

Comment: Since you want floats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double

Comment: Or read from `std::istringstream` as `float`, `char`, `float`, `char`, `float`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a line of a csv file into a std::vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310947/splitting-a-line-of-a-csv-file-into-a-stdvector)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this problem.  Personally, I would implement a linked-list to save each line read out of the file in its own memory buffer.  Once the entire file was read out, I would know how many lines were in the file and process each line in the list using `strtok` and `strtod` to convert the values.

Here's some ***pseudo code*** to get you rolling:

```
// Read the lines from the file and store them in a list
while ( getline (myfile,line) )
{
    ListObj.Add( line );
}

// Allocate memory for your two-dimensional array
float **Vertices = (float **)malloc( ListObj.Count() * 3 * sizeof(float) );

// Read each line from the list, convert its values to floats
//  and store the values in your array
int i = j = 0;
while ( line = ListObj.Remove() )
{
    sVal = strtok( line, ",\r\n" );
    fVal = (float)strtod( sVal, &pStop );
    Verticies[i][j++] = fVal;

    sVal = strtok( sVal + strlen(sVal) + 1, ",\r\n" );
    fVal = (float)strtod( sVal, &pStop );
    Verticies[i][j++] = fVal;

    sVal = strtok( sVal + strlen(sVal) + 1, ",\r\n" );
    fVal = (float)strtod( sVal, &pStop );
    Verticies[i][j] = fVal;

    i++;
    j = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code after edit is right.You can access a vector value in c++ just like you access the values in a normal c++ array.Like `classdata[i]`You can find more here . [Vector reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/)

And as for your question about converting string to float.In c++ you can directly do this by using stof ie `stof(-0.883)` you can find reference again here [string to float](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/)

Best of luck and hope this helps :)