# How to adapt a string splitting algorithm using pointers so it uses iterators instead?

Tags: c++

The code below comes from an answer to [this question on string splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top). It uses pointers, and a comment on that answer suggested it could be adapted for `std::string`. How can I use the features of `std::string` to implement the same algorithm, for example using iterators?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split(const char *str, char c = ',')
{
    vector<string> result;

    do
    {
        const char *begin = str;

        while(*str != c && *str)
          str++;

        result.push_back(string(begin, str));
    } while (0 != *str++);

    return result;
}
```

Ok so I obviously replaced char by string but then I noticed he is using a pointer to the beginning of the character. Is that even possible for strings? How do the loop termination criteria change? Is there anything else I need to worry about when making this change?

Comment: You could replace `const char *str` by `const std::string& str` and see how far you get. If you get stuck at some point, this would make a good question, but at the moment there is no evidence for any effort made from your side

Comment: You might want to read about [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin).

Comment: I'd attempt to create a `vector<string>` like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28880605/2642059

Comment: The real question is "how do I transform this algorithm written in terms of pointers to one in terms of iterators, or another concept that is readily modelled by the `std::string` type. As such, it's not a duplicate of a question about how to split a string; it's just in need of editing.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that is exactly what I am looking for, phrasing myself correctly was rather difficult. Will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) instead of pointers. Iterators provide a way to traverse containers, and can usually be thought of as analogous to pointers.

In this case, you can use the `begin()` member function (or `cbegin()` if you don't need to modify the elements) of a `std::string` object to obtain an iterator that references the first character, and the `end()` (or `cend()`) member function to obtain an iterator for "one-past-the-end".

For the inner loop, your termination criterion is the same; you want to stop when you hit the delimiter on which you'll be splitting the string. For the outer loop, instead of comparing the character value against `'\0'`, you can compare the iterator against the end iterator you already obtained from the `end()` member function. The rest of the algorithm is pretty similar; iterators work like pointers in terms of dereference and increment:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, const char delim = ',') {
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    auto end = str.cend();
    auto iter = str.cbegin();

    while (iter != end) {
        auto begin = iter;

        while (iter != end && *iter != delim) ++iter;

        result.push_back(std::string(begin, iter));
        if (iter != end) ++iter; // See note (**) below.
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note the subtle difference in the inner loop condition: it now tests whether we've hit the end *before* trying to dereference. This is because we can't dereference an iterator that points to the end of a container, so we must check this before trying to dereference. The original algorithm assumes that a null character ends the string, so we're ok to dereference a pointer to that position.

**(**)** The validity of `iter++ != end` when `iter` is already `end` is under discussion in [Are end+1 iterators for std::string allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657050/are-end1-iterators-for-stdstring-allowed)
I've added this `if` statement to the original algorithm to break the loop when `iter` reaches `end` in the inner loop. This avoids adding one to an iterator which is already the `end` iterator, and avoids the potential problem.

Comment: Note: there is a discussion on the validity of `iter++ != end` where `iter` could already be `end`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657050/are-end1-iterators-for-stdstring-allowed

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've added a check for the case where `iter` reaches `end` within the inner loop. I'd prefer to write this kind of thing as a `for` loop over the range defined by the iterators, ensuring that this `end + 1` scenario cannot happen, but I wanted to keep the code as close as possible to the original for the purposes of answering the question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any reason not to write the outer loop as `for (auto iter = str.cbegin(); iter != end; ++iter)`?

Comment: The only thing your test at the end of the outer loop does, is increment the iterator - it can never exit the loop because you have already checked that in the preceeding line.

Comment: Final comment:  adding to `result` with `result.emplace_back(begin, iter)` constructs the final string directly in place.  Total is `for (auto iter = str.cbegin(); iter != end; ++iter) { auto begin = iter; while (iter != end && *iter != delim) ++iter; result.emplace_back(begin, iter); }`

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, see the comment at the bottom of the post - there was some discussion about the validity of `iter++` when `iter == end`, so I added the `if` to avoid that confusion, but didn't otherwise modify the code. The purpose was to illustrate how to transform the code from the question to use iterators, not to provide a perfectly efficient snippet people can copy & paste without thinking about it!

Comment: @Andrew OK.  But avoiding `iter++ != end` when `iter` already equals `end` means you have to change the loop termination.  At the very least you should change it to `... if (iter == end) break; iter++ } while (true)`.  You may not want to make it perfect, but I don't think you should make it deliberately bad.

Comment: @MartinBonner there's nothing deliberate about it.