# convert string vector into double 2-d array vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, 2d-vector

What is a good way to convert `vector<string>` line to `vector<vector <double> >` d?

I have 500x9 vector string data reading from a file,

```
vector<string> line;
```

I need to convert this string vector into 2D vector array of size (500 rows, 9 columns)

```
vector<vector <double> > d;
```

Code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    /// read file data ///
    std::ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("somefile.txt");
    std::vector<string> lines;
    std::string str;
    while(getline(myfile,str))
        lines.push_back(str);
    myfile.close();

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > data;
    /// convert string to double ///
    std::transform(lines.begin(), lines.end(), data.begin(), std::stod);

}
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion: open an editor, and write some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: @Barmar .. thanks for help with editing ...,

no, its way different, I am already able to read data from .txt file not csv, my main problem is to convert string vector into 2d - vector of doubles .. later I will have to extract individual columns

Comment: How is that different? You have a comma-separated list of numbers, and the CSV reader will return a 2d vector.

Comment: well 1st it is not comma-separated .. its just spaces  and I think it can be solved in one or two lines of code .. instead of creating new class like in that question

I have problem with this line of code.. and this should transform strings into double. ..correct me if I am wrong ? 


std::transform(lines.begin(), lines.end(), data.begin(), std::stod);

thanks for your help

Comment: @Barmar I'd also argue that parsing data in a `vector<string>` is far different from reading Comma Separated Values from a stream. ([Though using a `sregex_token_iterator` may help them feel similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28880605/2642059).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm about as big a fan of standard algorithms as you can find. But I believe your best case here is a good old fashion `while`-loop (this is particularly true if you're not sure that `line` is divisible by 9: [Using an iterator to Divide an Array into Parts with Unequal Size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36425393/2642059))

```
vector<vector<double>> d(line.size() / 9, vector<double>(9));

for(auto i = 0U; i + 9 <= line.size(); i += 9) {
    transform(next(cbegin(line), i), next(begin(line), i + 9), begin(d[i / 9]), [](const auto& it){return stod(it);});
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/vexjjO)

Note the call to [`stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is wrapped in a lambda.

- `transform(cbegin(lines), cend(lines), begin(d[i / 9]), stod)` won't work because the compiler doesn't know whether you're calling `double stod(const string&, size_t*)` or `double stod(const wstring&, size_t*)`
- `transform(cbegin(lines), cend(lines), begin(d[i / 9]), static_cast<double (*)(const string&, size_t*)>(stod))` won't work because the defaulted second argument is not preserved by the function pointer
- `transform(cbegin(lines), cend(lines), begin(d[i / 9]), bind(static_cast<double (*)(const string&, size_t*)>(stod), placeholders::_1, 0))` does work equivalently to the lambda

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.. much appreciated your time and effort  .. this method works well though I managed to do it another way as well :)

Comment: Incidentally, cause I didn't do this in my example, you can print `d` using: `for(const auto& i : d) copy(cbegin(i), cend(i), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, "\t"));`