# Java String Split using Regex with Escape Character

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string which needs to be split based on a delimiter(:). This delimiter can be escaped by a character (say '?'). Basically the delimiter can be preceded by any number of escape character. Consider below example string:

```
a:b?:c??:d???????:e
```

Here, after the split, it should give the below list of string:

```
a 
b?:c?? 
d???????:e
```

Basically, if the delimiter (:) is preceded by even number of escape characters, it should split. If it is preceded by odd number of escape characters, it should not split. Is there a solution to this with regex?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Similar question has been asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901978/regex-and-escaped-and-unescaped-delimiter), But the answers are not working for this use case.

Update:
The solution with the regex: (?:\?.|[^:?])* correctly split the string. However, this also gives few empty strings. If + is given instead of *, even the real empty matches also ignored. (Eg:- a::b gives only a,b)

Comment: What is the expected result for `::a:b?:c??::d???????:e::`?

Comment: For the above string, it should split with following strings:
<empty>,a,b?c??,<empty>,d???????:e,<empty>

Comment: Aha, so the first and last (start and end of string) are not necessary.

Comment: Actually, even if they are there it is not a problem.

Comment: Good, I added all possible solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scenario 1: No empty matches**

You may use

```
(?:\?.|[^:?])+
```

Or, following the pattern in the linked answer

```
(?:\?.|[^:?]++)+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZnsW3/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `\?.` - a `?` (the delimiter) followed with any char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^:?]`  - any char but the `:` (your delimiter char) and `?` (the escape char)
- `)+` - 1 or more repetitions.

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?:\\?.|[^:?]++)+";
```

In case the input contains line breaks, prepend the pattern with `(?s)` (like `(?s)(?:\\?.|[^:?])+`) or compile the pattern with `Pattern.DOTALL` flag.

**Scenario 2: Empty matches included**

You may add `(?<=:)(?=:)` alternative to the above pattern to match empty strings between `:` chars, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZnsW3/2):

```
String s = "::a:b?:c??::d???????:e::";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?>\\?.|[^:?])+|(?<=:)(?=:)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("'" + matcher.group() + "'"); 
}
```

Output of the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fe3lR8):

```
''
'a'
'b?:c??'
''
'd???????:e'
''
```

**Note** that if you want to also match empty strings at the start/end of the string, use `(?<![^:])(?![^:])` rather than `(?<=:)(?=:)`.